# Как собирать семантическое ядро

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы, семантика, продвижение

Не могу понять все-таки как собирать семантическое ядро. Где-то в интернете прочитал, что ключевых запросов должно быть как можно больше. Например я собрал 2000 запросов, а у меня на сайте всего 20 страниц. Если я все запросы раскидаю по страницам, получится в среднем по 100 ключевиков на странице. Разве не сочтет это поисковик за спам, да и не особо читабельно будет. Может какие-то запросы стоит откидывать?  Просто ради примера взял запрос "**летние мужские туфли**" собрал похожие:

> - летние мужские туфли купить
> - летние мужские туфли недорого
> - летние мужские туфли 2016
> - летние мужские туфли италия
> - летние мужски туфли россия
> - летние мужские туфли питер
> - летние мужские туфли новинки 2016
> - летние мужские туфли ретро
> - летние мужские туфли купить в москве
> - летние мужские туфли в москве
> - летние мужские туфли москва
> - летние мужские туфли распродажа
> - итальянские летние мужские туфли

К примеру, я хочу продвигать определенную страницу, посвященную летним мужским туфлям, для этой страницы собрал семантическое ядро. И что, мне все 13 ключевиков (хотя могу еще больше написать) с 13-ю повторениями "летние мужские туфли" кидать на одну страницу? По-моему будет жесткий переспам. Или может я не совсем правильно собираю семантическое ядро?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете создать каталог указанных товаров - туфель и разбивать/сегментировать исходный код страницы с ***семантическими элементами ХТМЛ5***. Например, создайте отдельную секцию для каждой категории с элементом **seсtion** или **article** (если длинное описание, типа статьи) - [**инфо W3**](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp). Необходимо следить за вложенностью этих элементов и правильно указывать последовательность тегов титле (h). Для контроля вы можете применить [**этот валидатор**](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) с выбором фильтра **outline** и смотреть внизу секции **Heading-level outline + Structural outline**. Также вы можете применять разметку структурированными данными для одного конкретного продукта как [**Product**](https://schema.org/Product) или же для каталога товаров как [**DataCatalog**](https://schema.org/DataCatalog) или как [**BreadcrumbList**](https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList).

Comment: Вопрос вообще о другом. Во всех статьях, курсах и прочей байде говорится о том, что нужно собрать как можно больше ключевиков. Конкретный пример, для "летние мужские туфли" - например собрал 30 тысяч (как можно больше) ключевиков - и куда их на 20-30 каталожных страниц раскидать?  не бред ли? Непонятно для чего советуется собрать огромное количество ключевиков, если будет использовано всего грубо говоря 500 из них

Comment: Сейчас алгоритм Гугл уже не смотрит нам ключевые слова. Но смотрит на скорость загрузки на мобильну мобильность, на длинный хвост и так далее.  Для скорости помогает семантика хтмл5.

Comment: этого не может быть, иначе можно было бы писать статьи про "велосипеды" ключевым словом "пиво" - но сейчас такого нет. и вопрос опять не об этом.